# undefined reference to sin and exp in c

Tags: c, compilation, math.h

I am trying to compile a bunch of different object files into an executable file using this command:

```
gcc -Wall -Ilib -lm -Itest/lib -o test/test_passwd test/test_cases/test_passwd.c build/tests/hills_quad_two.o build/tests/hills_blank_quad.o build/tests/climber.o build/tests/hills_double.o build/tests/hills_multi_var.o build/tests/test.o build/tests/hills_sin.o build/tests/hills_exp.o
```

and I am getting two errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build/tests/hills_sin.o: in function `hills_sin_function':
hills_sin.c:(.text+0x100): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: hills_sin.c:(.text+0x11f): undefined reference to `sin'
/usr/bin/ld: build/tests/hills_exp.o: in function `hills_exp_function':
hills_exp.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `exp'
/usr/bin/ld: hills_exp.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `exp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have linked the math library using -lm in the compilation command as well as using `#include <math.h>` in a header file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that stops it from compiling. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This is a link time error. Try putting the `-lm` at the end of the command line (e.g. _after_ the `.o` files that need it)

Comment: This a duplicate.  Finding it will be mildly fiddly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i found it I guess, even uses sin

Comment: Looks appropriate.  Probably one of many possibilities.